# Change text on hover using Css and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button on my website that when you click expand some text. And I need to make so when you hover mouse over that button, text changes to "Expand" and when text is expanded, and you hover over same button, text needs to be changed to "collapse".
Here is my code:
HTML:

```
  <button id="btnSlideUp" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm title">
        <h1 class="jumbotron-heading" id="title">TEXT</h1> 
   </button>
         <p  class="lead text-muted" id="p1">TEXT</p>
```

Css:

```
 #p1{
   display:none; 
  }
```

jQuery:

```
var isUp=true;

        $('#btnSlideUp').click(function() {

            if(isUp){
                $('#p1').slideDown(1000);
                isUp=false;
            }else{
                $('#p1').slideUp(1000);
                isUp=true;
                }
            });
```

Thank you very much for any help given!

Comment: FYI: You mean expand, not expend. ;-)

Comment: @CBroe yep, English is not my first language, thanks for pointing this out, i will edit it rn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [.hover](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) on $('#btnSlideUp')?

```js
var isUp = true;

$('#btnSlideUp').hover(
  function() {
    if (isUp) {
      $(this).find('h1').text('Expand');
    } else {
      $(this).find('h1').text('Collapse');
    }
  },
  function() {
    $(this).find('h1').text('TEXT');
  }
)

$('#btnSlideUp').click(function() {
  if(isUp){
    $('#p1').slideDown(1000);
    isUp=false;
  }else{
    $('#p1').slideUp(1000);
    isUp=true;
  }
});
```

```css
#p1{
  display:none; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnSlideUp" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm title">
  <h1 class="jumbotron-heading" id="title">TEXT</h1> 
 </button>
 <p  class="lead text-muted" id="p1">TEXT</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using jQuery events you can handle this with CSS using classes and the hover selector.

Something like:

```
button.expanded::before {
    content: 'Expanded';
}

button.expanded:hover::before {
    content: 'Collapse';
}

button::before {
    content: 'Collapsed';
}

button:hover::before {
    content: 'Expand';
}
```

Then you can just apply your classes with jQuery and you the CSS takes care of it

Answer (score 0):

Well just as you used the .click event listener, you can use the .hover function

```
$('#btnSlideUp').hover(function() { /*do whatever you need here */ });
```

https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 0):

You can add an hover event to toggle this, I am using a flag to set the hover text for the button, if its `c` the button should say `collapse` else `expand`.

```js
var isUp=true, button = $('title'), text = $('#p1'), mode;

        $('#btnSlideUp').click(function() {

            if(isUp){
                text.slideDown(1000);
                isUp=false;
                setTimeout(function(){mode = 'c'}, 1000);
            }else{
                text.slideUp(1000);
                isUp=true;
                setTimeout(function(){mode = 'e'}, 1000);
                }
            });
            $('#btnSlideUp').hover(function() {

            if(mode === 'c'){
                $(this).children().html('Collapse');
            }else{
                $(this).children().html('Expand');
                }
            }, function(){$(this).children().html('TEXT');});
```

```css
#p1{
   display:none; 
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnSlideUp" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm title">
        <h1 class="jumbotron-heading" id="title">TEXT</h1> 
   </button>
         <p  class="lead text-muted" id="p1">TEXT</p>
```